# How to display the date of the next first Sunday in PHP without specifying month

Tags: php, date

I work for a church and we have new member classes on the first, second, and third Sunday of each month. We have three parts to the class and at the bottom of each description on the website I would like it to list the next date for that class.

If it has already past I want it to go ahead and show the date for the next month. For example: The next Growth Track 101 is November 2, The next Growth Track 201 is November 9, The next Growth Track 301 is November 16. I saw a couple of similar older posts but with no solution at least that fits our needs.

I need this to be generic and be able to leave it permanently because with everything on my plate this is something that always falls through the cracks. Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you search for `strtotime("last Sunday")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Next sunday"));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted. Please also reread the question and ensure that your answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtotime` function should be able to do this:

```
$first = strtotime('first sunday of next month');
$second = strtotime('second sunday of next month');
$third = strtotime('third sunday of next month');

echo date("Y-m-d", $first), '<br />', date("Y-m-d", $second), '<br />', date("Y-m-d", $third);
```

The above outputs (as of Oct. 30th):

```
2014-11-02
2014-11-09
2014-11-16
```

Comment: For example if the first sunday of that current month had already past would it show it for next month but leave the rest for that current month since they have not happened yet? Also I have to have to code separate I have a lot more than just line breaks that I have to put in between each class. You can refer to to http://mysummitlife.com/growth-track/ where I want to put each date under the explanation for that class. Thanks!